# Regular Expression - joining two lines, but first number of joined 2nd line is deleted

Tags: regex

I have some sample data (simplified extract below - the real file contains 52,000 lines, with pairs of lines, the 2nd line of each pair is always a date field, and there are always 2 blank lines between each data pair):

```
The colour of money     20170233434 
10-DEC-2015


SOME TEST DATA      32423412123 
19-OCT-2015
```

I want to join each line up, using a Regular Expression (I am using TextPad, but I think the RegEx syntax is generic).

I am doing a replace search, and want to end up with this:

```
The colour of money     20170233434     10-DEC-2015


SOME TEST DATA      32423412123     19-OCT-2015
```

I am using this in the "Find what" field:

```
\n^[0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9]
```

And replacing with NULL.

The end result I am getting is almost there:

```
The colour of money     20170233434 0-DEC-2015


SOME TEST DATA      32423412123 9-OCT-2015
```

But not quite, because the first digit of the date values are being stripped out.

How would I modify the RegEx to not delete the first number of the 2nd line? I tried to replace with `[0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9]` but that just put that entire string in front of each date field, and still stripped out the first number of the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just search for this

```
\r?\n(\d{1,2}\-)
```

And replace it with `$1`. See the [live example here](https://regex101.com/r/XZNNzo/1).

---

If you want to replace it with `null`, you can also use a lookahead:

```
\r?\n(?=\d{1,2}\-)
```

And replace it with `null`. See the [live example here](https://regex101.com/r/XZNNzo/2).

---

Those regular expressions only match for a newline character (in UNIX `\n` or Windows `\r\n`) followed by 1 or 2 characters of a number and finally followed by a dash. If you want to be more specific, you could also use this regular expression:

```
\r?\n(\d{1,2}\-[A-Z]{3}\-\d{4})
```

Or with a lookahead respectively:

```
\r?\n(?=\d{1,2}\-[A-Z]{3}\-\d{4})
```

You could even check for the double linebreaks after the statement ([live example](https://regex101.com/r/XZNNzo/5)):

```
\r?\n(\d{1,2}\-[A-Z]{3}\-\d{4}(?:\r?\n){2})
```

Or with a lookahead respectively ([live example](https://regex101.com/r/XZNNzo/3)):

```
\r?\n(?=\d{1,2}\-[A-Z]{3}\-\d{4}(?:\r?\n){2})
```

Comment: Thank you! `\r?\n(?=\d{1,2}\-)` did the trick. That regex101.com is very handy too.